# Does strcat() return an error as strcat_s() does?

Tags: c, strcat, strcat-s

Does `strcat()` return an error as `strcat_s()` does? Can `strcat()` replace strcat_s()`?

```
 char str1[50] = "To be, or not to be, ";
 char str2[] = "that is the question.";
 int retval = strcat_s(str1, sizeof str1, str2);
 if(retval)
     printf("There was an error joining the strings. Error code = %d",retval);
 else
     printf("The combined strings:\n%s\n", str1);
```

Comment: suggest reading the man page for strcat() and comparing it to the man page for strcat_s().   The man page(s) are very informative about returned values.  A 'google' of strcat will find plenty of references about the limitations of strcat() and the preference to use strncat().

Comment: thanks for reference.

Answer (score 3):

`strcat()` does not return an error code but you can still use it incorrectly and run into errors. It can be used instead of `strcat_s()` like

```c
strcat(str1, str2);
```

It may help you to look up a reference for C functions like [cppreference.com/w/c](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) to find out the answer to similar questions like this.